# Difficulty in understanding negation and parentheses in math logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm working on a exercise from "Logic for Mathematicians" by A.G.Hamilton.I'm taking a logic and set theory course and I have lost my first year "foundation of math" goods.
I'm faced with this proposition :
¬((p→(¬q))→r)
I reviewed my past material and I couldn't figure it out how should I deal with the above negation and parentheses. Is "negation" for the whole "((p→(¬q))→r)" ? how should I read the above proposition? is it "if p→(¬q)) then r" or is it "if p then (¬q))→r" ? How this negation and parentheses workout together?
I'm ashamed that I have forgotten a lot of this basic knowledge.
FINAL NOTE: This is not a homework question.
Thanks for your time and help in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "Is "negation" for the whole ?" Yes; the outermost negation acts on all the formula enclosed between the outermost pair of parentheses.

Comment: The formula on which we have to apply negation is $[(p \to (\lnot q)) \to r]$. In this case truth table may help: the negation of $(A \to B)$ is $(A \land \lnot B)$.

Comment: Thus, the result will be: $[(p \to (\lnot q)) \land \lnot r]$.

Comment: How to read the formula ? First of all, parentheses **must** match; thus, you have to remove them from the outer in pairs: $((p→(¬q))→r)$ is "if $(p→(¬q))$, then $r$".

Answer (score 1):

You should remember that $a→b$ is equivalent to $¬a∨b$, you can prove by truth table.Therefore,for $¬((p→(¬q))→r)$ ,we can translate it to **¬(if(if p then ¬q) then r)** or

=$¬((¬p∨¬q)→r)$

=$¬((p∧q)∨r)$

=$((¬p∨¬q)∧¬r)$ (De Morgan's laws)

=$((p→¬q)∧¬r)$

(if p then ¬q) and ¬r

How to read parentheses and negation

((¬p)∧r)=(¬p∧r)=¬p∧r

¬((p)∧r)=¬(p∧r)=¬p∨¬r